# Symfony4, unable to minify CSS using webpack

Tags: webpack, minify, symfony4

I have a symfony 4 web application and I'm attempting to minify the CSS however it is not working. I've been trying this for hours and I havent been able to have it serve a minified version. Am I doing something wrong?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
   // the public path used by the web server to access the previous 
directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .enablePostCssLoader()


    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
     .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    // .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    // .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a 
global variable
    // .autoProvidejQuery()



;


module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        // include whatever plugins you want
        // but make sure you install these via yarn or npm!

        // add browserslist config to package.json (see below)
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
}
```

Comment: What command did you try to compile with webpackEncore ?
If I remember correctly, you need to compile for production to minify, but I'm not sure now.

Comment: I was doing it with yarn encore dev. However when I did it with yarn encore production it minified it. THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER!

Comment: I was not sure about it but good that's it. I'll make an answer, so You can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compile your assets for production with `yarn encore production`

I'm not sure but `npm encore production` or `./node_modules/.bin/encore production` should work too.